# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column ' ' not found

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have strange situation, with hibernate I am generating native/sql query for getting data from dinamic table, tables are generated from code so I have not entities for each table, I find tables by prefix. So generated query working well when I run it in mysql console, but with hibernate when I try to fetch data and map it to one general entity I am always have exception about missing column.

```
 SQLQuery query1 = getSession().createSQLQuery(sqlLinked.toString());  
     List<MyGlobalEntity> objectList = (List<MyGlobalEntity>) query1
         .addEntity(MyGlobalEntity.class).list();
```

Hibernate complained like

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'col name' not found.
```

But global entity have all fields which have generated entities.
And SQL worked wee from console.

Who can suggest something?

here is a query , short version

```
select *  from g_table where  id > 0 AND  x_5 >='2001-12-31'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have added query in question, it is bit long, but it is working and return result in console mode.

Comment: for example it complain about column Idx_1, but in select table no columns but that name

Comment: Your question is to generalized to understand, the error you are seeing is **specific** to your code. So either post everything or give more information. Giving hints on errors, SQL and code snippets and assuming we can debug it is a bit an overstretch, If you need help **POST EVERYTHING** to get an answer.